# Angular can't start properly

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When I open it in my browser I get this error and pages did not load.

```
core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":400,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://127.0.0.1:8080/signups/summary","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8080/signups/summary: 400 OK","error":{"timestamp":"2021-04-30T11:08:22.168+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/signups/summary"}}
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:793)
    at zone-evergreen.js:707
    at rejected (tslib.es6.js:72)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:365)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:27436)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at zone-evergreen.js:851
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:400)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27424)
```

The problem is that I don't even have this endpoint `http://127.0.0.1:8080/signups/summary` it should be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/summary`.

One thing that might be helpful. I have two child modules. One of them works fine and other one is not. When I go somewhere inside `auth` module it works and send the correct api request but in the `pages` thats not the case.

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: { shouldRedirect: true },
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: AppHomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule),
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''},
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: false,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

I did uninstall and reinstall node, angular everything but it didn't help. Don't know why this is happening and trying to fix this for hours now. I would appreciate any pointers in this matter.

**EDIT**

The problem was in `PagesModule`. The imports for the module was broken causing a routing problem.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule, // <= Moved back to top
    ThemeModule,
    NbMenuModule,
    SignupModule,
    ReportModule,
    UserModule,
    UnauthorizedModule,
//  PagesRoutingModule, <= Was here

  ],
  declarations: [
    PagesComponent,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

Doing this change fixed the problem.

Comment: Try removing `"../src/**/*.ts"` from your tsconfig file

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could get rid of this problem by updating angular-cli with the following command without interfering `tsconfig.app.json` file.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

OR

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```